# Changing the main family mid-document—is there a better approach?

Tags: fonts

I'm using Monotype Ehrhardt for my body text, but use Computer Modern¹ for example output. I ran into an issue where it turned out that the output routine happened to get activated when Computer Modern was the default text. This, in turn, caused my page headers to be set in CM rather than Ehrhardt. (It was all the more surprising since I only request CM inside of a group, usually inside of a box, in fact.)

I ended up adding this after `\SetMainFont`:

```
\edef\DocumentBodyFont{%
   \noexpand\def\noexpand\f@series{\f@series}%     
   \noexpand\def\noexpand\f@family{\f@family}%     
   \noexpand\def\noexpand\f@encoding{\f@encoding}%     
   \noexpand\def\noexpand\f@shape{\f@shape}%     
   \noexpand\def\noexpand\f@size{\f@size}%
   \noexpand\selectfont
 }
```

which lets me put `\DocumentBodyFont` in the page headers and get my expected results, but I'm wondering if there's a better approach (I would have to assume I'm not the only one to encounter something like this).

For completeness's sake, here's the relevant part of the macro that I use to switch to lmr for LaTeX output examples:

```
\def\rmdefault{lmr}\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
\def\bfdefault{bx}%
```

I suspect there might be some redundancy in the first line—some of this code predates fontspec and barely postdates NFSS.

1. Actually Latin Modern.

Comment: the headings are set using `\reset@font`  so should not be affected by a page break in verbatim

Comment: It's not verbatim, it's lmr text for showing LaTeX output. I've edited the question to include what I do.

Comment: either way something is wrong, your main document font should be set by `\reset@font` and that is reset locally by the output routine before setting the page head and foot specifically to stop what you describe from happening.

Comment: I think I'm running very much an edge case here since I have an environment where I want `\normalfont` to have a different meaning than it does in the rest of the document.

Comment: hmm you could separate \normalfont and \reset@font, the default definition is `\let\reset@font\normalfont`

Comment: or set your example code in a vbox so no page breaking then unvbox it so it can page break without any macro scope issues